# Как пофиксить циклический редирект?

Tags: php, веб-программирование, .htaccess, websocket, ssl

Есть сайт у которого для домена получен бесплатный ssl, который соответственно не распространяется на поддомен, но для поддомена он как бы и не нужен, вот сам [сайт](https://anonimayzer-vk.com/) на нем есть ссылка на поддомен "зайти на вк через..." после нажатия на которую получается циклический редирект (ошибка 301), делал все со 100% точностью по [этому](https://github.com/php-youtube/php-anonymizer-v2) мануалу, причем без ssl на основном домене все работало отлично. Заранее всех благодарю, может кто в курсе в чем может быть причина редиректа?

Answer (score 0):

Для решения данного вопроса в настройках хостинг аккаунта была отключена автоматическая переадресация сайта на https и был написан htaccess в котором была настроена переадресация только для домена, после этого редирект на поддомене перестал функционировать, соответственно данный вопрос был решен. Всем спасибо!